# Render controller and get form errors from child

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a template where I render a widget which contains a form:

```
{{ render(controller('ApplicationDemoBundle:Demo:newWidget', {'demo' : entity })) }}
```

The newWidgetAction calls a createAction:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Demo();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('demo_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    )
    // Something like this would be awesome with passing the form containing errors with
    // return $this->redirect($this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

Imagine the submitted form (user acts in show theme) produces an error. This would make a return to the newWidget template which does not display the full layout.

My question is now: What is the right way to pass the errors from the child controller (newWidget) to the main template (show)?, without modifying the showActions function parameter to pass the formerrors over there.

*There is a similar thread to this question: [Symfony2 render and form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286169/symfony2-render-and-form)
In this case where sessions used but I'm more than curious if this is the way to go.*

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each fragment (a sub-controller) uses a virtual request.  This is to protect the original request from modification by possibly unexpected forwards, and a fragment is essentially a forward taking place during a rendering stage.

It is possible to access the top level request using:
`$this->container->get('request');` then handing the request with the form in the fragment, but this may get very confusing very quickly if you are using multiple forms per page.

My strategy is to follow a convention that limits the number of validated form on a page to just one.  Any other forms don't require validation, or it is otherwise impossible for a form to be submitted incorrectly (hacked forms would throw server side exceptions, but the user should only see those if they are being naughty).

Try to structure your template inheritance to accommodate navigation to forms, while always showing most of the same layouts and data.  You can do this by expanding the use of fragments which gives the bonus of separating your display logic.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. 

The idea with handing the form into the top level request is very interesting I think and could be even with more than one form a good implementation if a solid concept is set up. I'm wondering if somebody ever did this for more than one form? But also if there are other suggestions?

But as far as I can see now I disagree with your strategy to limit the number of validated forms to one. It is more than common these days to offer the user more than just one possibility on a single page. Why should we just be able to manage one single form?

Comment: Its a practice really, it is entirely possible to validate multiple forms, theres just no 'pretty' way of doing it, as far as I have tried.

Comment: Which is the reason why I created this post here :)